# remember_me with warden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, remember-me, warden

For my lastest project I'm using https://github.com/hassox/rails_warden. It suits my needs very well except that I can't find a good way to implement remember_me. I know that it's notoriously difficult to get remember_me right from a security point of view so I'm hoping there's a project out there that will do the job. Anyone seen anything or get a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), which is an authentication solution on top of Warden, has a [rememberable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/rememberable.rb) implementation.

Comment: I was aware that devise had a rememberable implementation, I hadn't realised it was a warden strategy though. That's perfect, I can just plug it in as the first strategy in my warden config. Will integrate and confirm it works.

Comment: I would be interested in the answer without relying on devise because I am trying implement in a sinatra app.

Answer (score 6):

Ok here's how I solved it

```
 # User model must have remember_token attribute

 # in config.ru
 use Rack::Cookies
 run MyApp

  # in lib/strategies.rb
  Strategies.add(:cookie) do
    def valid?
      env['rack.cookies']['user.remember.token']      
    end

    def authenticate!
      if user = User.find_by_remember_token(cookies['user.remember.token'])
        success! user
      else
        fail! "Could not log in"
      end
    end
  end

  Manager.after_authentication :scope => :user do |user, auth, opts|
    auth.env['rack.cookies']['user.remember.token'] = user.generate_remember_token! # sets its remember_token attribute to some large random value and returns the value
  end

  Manager.before_logout :scoper => :user do |user, auth, opts|
    user.update_attribute :remember_token, nil
  end
```