# "Remember Me" feature in Warden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, warden

How can I implement a "Remember Me" feature using Warden?

I've looked at the remember me strategy that Devise (based on Warden) uses but have no clue how to adapt that to my barebones warden authentication.

Comment: Its pretty straight forward - create a signed cookie with the serialized user (the user ID), and an expiry date. When you authenticate you check the session for a user first. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/e54326c19c68f10df2548fcaaab411e93178b279/lib/devise/controllers/rememberable.rb

Maybe if you add some code with your Warden strategy we can give you some more concrete advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remember\_me with warden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461984/remember-me-with-warden)